# How to click on an input type"submit" button without submiting the whole form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to click the following line of code:

```
<input title="Add To Cart" name="pdp_addtocart" value="Add To Cart" type="submit" class="active_step">
```

I have tried the .click() form and it doesnt work. I need the code in javascript.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the onclick event to the button:

```
<input onclick="return false;".... />
```

return false in the event will halt the form submission.

or using pure javascript:

```
theButton.onclick = function() {
    return false;
};
```

Edit:

jQuery version:

```
$theBtn.click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Also check out [preventDefault](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Answer (score 2):

With *Jquery*:

```
var my_btn = $('input[name="pdp_addtocart"]');

my_btn.click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault(); //This avoid  the default behavior of the button
  //Your Stuff
});
```

In case your form still sending add this line:

```
   $('form').submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); //This avoid the behavior of sending the form
    });
```

Comment: SHould be the accepted answer, +1 for explicit comments.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `<input type="submit" />`?

You could use a `<input type="button" />` instead.